# How to create cardano light wallet?

Tags: cardano

I am trying to create light wallet of cardano. these are steps I followed but not able to create it. It create only full node wallet.

**METHOD 1**
first I run full node

```
cardano-node run \
    --topology /root/cardano-node/mainnet-topology.json \
    --database-path /root/cardano-node/db/ \
    --socket-path /root/cardano-node/node.socket \
    --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
    --port 1225 \
    --config /root/cardano-node/mainnet-config.json
```

then connected with node using cardano wallet

```
cardano-wallet serve \
    --port 8090 \
    --mainnet \
    --database /root/cardano-node/db \
    --node-socket /root/cardano-node/node.socket
```

then create wallet using `cardano-wallet wallet create from-recovery-phrase mytwallet`
but this generates only full node wallet. please correct me if i am doing something wrong.

**METHOD 2**
by using blockfrost api and IOHK github cardano-wallet binaries I able to connect with blockfrost but not able to create light wallet.
IOHK - https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/user-guide/cli

`cardano-wallet serve --light --blockfrost-token-file /root/blockfrost-mainnet.key --mainnet --port 8090`
`cardano-wallet wallet create from-recovery-phrase mytwallet`

after this I got error something like this

> cardano-wallet.main:Info:4] [2022-05-02 14:58:20.48 UTC] Wallet
> backend server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8090/
> [cardano-wallet.api-server:Info:32] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.29 UTC]
> [RequestId 0] [POST] /v2/wallets
> [cardano-wallet.wallet-engine:Notice:38] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.50 UTC]
> 68d07b25: Reward balance worker has exited. Prelude.undefined
> CallStack (from HasCallStack):   error, called at
> libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err   undefined, called at
> src/Cardano/Wallet/Shelley/Network/Blockfrost.hs:222:26 in
> cardano-wallet-2022.4.27-8yWedlbE4ve5DTbU3euDG0:Cardano.Wallet.Shelley.Network.Blockfrost
> [cardano-wallet.wallet-engine:Notice:34] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.57 UTC]
> Worker has exited: Action has finished
> [cardano-wallet.network:Info:47] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.79 UTC] Update
> watcher with tip: 92708059<-[ee0df56e-59937200#7196414]. Callback
> start. [cardano-wallet.network:Info:47] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.79 UTC]
> Update watcher with tip: 92708059<-[ee0df56e-59937200#7196414].
> Callback exception: Prelude.undefined CallStack (from HasCallStack):
> error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
> undefined, called at
> src/Cardano/Wallet/Shelley/Network/Blockfrost.hs:215:39 in
> cardano-wallet-2022.4.27-8yWedlbE4ve5DTbU3euDG0:Cardano.Wallet.Shelley.Network.Blockfrost. [cardano-wallet.wallet-engine:Error:47] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.79 UTC]
> 68d07b25: Processing the pending local tx submission pool: exception:
> Prelude.undefined CallStack (from HasCallStack):   error, called at
> libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err   undefined, called at
> src/Cardano/Wallet/Shelley/Network/Blockfrost.hs:215:39 in
> cardano-wallet-2022.4.27-8yWedlbE4ve5DTbU3euDG0:Cardano.Wallet.Shelley.Network.Blockfrost
> [cardano-wallet.network:Info:42] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.79 UTC] Update
> watcher with tip: 92708059<-[ee0df56e-59937200#7196414]. Callback
> start. [cardano-wallet.wallet-engine:Error:42] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.79
> UTC] 68d07b25: Processing the pending local tx submission pool:
> exception: Prelude.undefined CallStack (from HasCallStack):   error,
> called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err   undefined,
> called at src/Cardano/Wallet/Shelley/Network/Blockfrost.hs:215:39 in
> cardano-wallet-2022.4.27-8yWedlbE4ve5DTbU3euDG0:Cardano.Wallet.Shelley.Network.Blockfrost
> [cardano-wallet.network:Info:42] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.79 UTC] Update
> watcher with tip: 92708059<-[ee0df56e-59937200#7196414]. Callback
> exception: Prelude.undefined CallStack (from HasCallStack):   error,
> called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err   undefined,
> called at src/Cardano/Wallet/Shelley/Network/Blockfrost.hs:215:39 in
> cardano-wallet-2022.4.27-8yWedlbE4ve5DTbU3euDG0:Cardano.Wallet.Shelley.Network.Blockfrost. [cardano-wallet.network:Info:40] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.80 UTC] Update
> watcher with tip: 92708059<-[ee0df56e-59937200#7196414]. Callback
> start. [cardano-wallet.network:Info:40] [2022-05-02 14:58:53.96 UTC]
> Update watcher with tip: 92708059<-[ee0df56e-59937200#7196414].
> Callback exception: BlockfrostException (ClientError
> BlockfrostNotFound).

[after entering recovery phrase and password i got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSEdU.png)

I am trying to create light wallet that does not sync every time with node.
thank you for support.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for the error you see in the `--light` mode. Its just not ready to be used yet, we're working on it.